# Printing elements from an array of wide characters in C Language

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, wcs

I have the following array of wide characters:

```
wchar_t alphabet[] = L"abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"; /*  array of wide characters */
```

Everytime I try to run the following code, a "segmentation violation" error occurs

```
printf("%ls %d\n", alphabet, wcslen (alphabet));
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= wcslen (alphabet); i++)
{
    printf("%ls\n", alphabet[i]);
}
```

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is overstepping the array.

Arrays are indexed from 0, so the condition in a loop like yours should always test with `<`, never with `<=`.

Also, you're printing single characters with `%s`, which is also wrong. It should be `%lc` for a single wide character.

Comment: The `<=` is not the problem here (in the `==` case, it will deref the valid trailing L'\0').

Comment: @unwind Surely the index of `alphabet[]` can range from `0 <= index <= wcslen (alphabet)`.  Agree OP is unnecessarily printing the terminating `(wchar_t)0`, but that is not causing the "segmentation violation".  Its the `%s` vs `%lc` that messes up things.

Answer (score 3):

`"%ls"` causes `alphabet[i]` to be interpreted as a pointer to a string.  Use `"%lc"`.